# Removing/Appending images with radio button

Tags: jquery, image, radio-button, append

I have a set of radio buttons I'm using to append and remove images within a div. My image sources are in a data set value within the radio buttons:

```
<input class="radioGroup" name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="radio1" data-source-image="/image1.jpg" data-source-desc="This is the First Image"> 
<label for="#radio1">Image 1</label><br /> 

<input class="radioGroup" name="radioGroup" type="radio" id="radio2" data-source-image="/image2.jpg" data-source-desc="This is the Second"> 
<label for="#radio2">Image 2</label>
```

I am appending the image with a class which corresponds with the radio buttons id and using that to remove the image if it's not checked:

```
 $('.selections input').live("change", function () {

    // 'Getting' data-attributes using dataset 
    var appendImg = $(this).data('sourceImage'); 
    var itemDesc = $(this).data('sourceDesc'); 
    var item = $(this).attr('id');

    if ($(this).is(':radio')) { 
        var radioGroupName = $(this).attr('name');
        var radioGroup = $('input[name="' + radioGroupName + '"]')

        radioGroup.each( function() {

            if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
                $('.imageContainer').append('<img src="' + appendImg + '" alt="' + itemDesc + '" class="' + item + '" />');
            }

            if ( ! $(this).attr("checked")){
                $('.imageContainer').children('img').remove('.' + item);
            }

        });


    } });
```

I can not get this to work though, I've tried multiple variations of this code each with slightly different results but none of them functioning as expected. In the case with this code, my first radio button does not function at all and the second radio button only adds its image.

Also, any other suggestion to clean up it up would be welcome (my radio check is there because there are other inputs I'm handling in this function).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're complicating things... If you wrap the radio input in the label you don't need the id:

```
<label><input type="radio" .../></label>
```

Then, instead of figuring out if it's a radio with the `live` event which is deprecated and I don't think you need either, you can use the `change` event of those particular radios. If you have dynamic radio inputs, then I'd suggest you use `on` on the closest static container, instead of `live` on `document`.

```
var $container = $('.imageContainer');

$('input[name=radioGroup]').change(function() {

  var $this = $(this), 
      imgSrc = $this.data('source-image'),
      imgDesc = $this.data('source-desc'),
      $img = $('<img/>', { src: imgSrc, alt: imgDesc });

  $('img', $container).remove(); // remove all images
  $container.append( $img ); // add the image linked to the current input

});
```

Since radios are exclusive, only one can be selected, you don't need to figure out if it's checked or not, and find other images, unless you already have images inside that same container. In that case, I would just create an extra wrapper for the images that are linked to radios.

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/isitos/1/edit

Comment: Thanks elclanrs, this is definitely a step in the right direction for me. I probably should have elaborated more, as I need to account for varying numbers of radio input groups and I can't clear all of the images within the container since I have other images displaying here via other checkboxes. Also, I know wrapping an input in a label is valid but I usually prefer keeping them separated.

Comment: Then you can use the class you were using, that should do it as well as adding all the groups you want to the change event. http://jsbin.com/isitos/2/edit <- demo seems weird because images are repeated but it works.